# Applications of the length of the continued fraction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

The fractions $n/q$ and $n/(n-q)$ can be representated by Hirzebruch continued fractions (also called Jung-Hirzebruch CF), the length of each we denote by $s$ and $t$. Is there  any bound for $s+t$?

Comment: What's a Hirzebruch continued fraction?

Comment: Gerry Myerson, it seems to be like a continued fraction but with minuses instead of pluses; see http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~voight/notes/cfrac.pdf page 9.
Also called Jung--Hirzebruch CF. 

 

Comment: My guess is that $s+t \leq n$, reached for $q=1$.

Comment: @quid, thanks. These would be what I called negative-regular continued fractions in my 1987 paper in Arch. Math. 

Comment: Correct link to "TORIC SURFACES AND CONTINUED FRACTIONS": http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/notes/cfrac.pdf